# vCard Parser for objC

Tags: objective-c, parsing, vcf-vcard

is there a good vCard parser for Objective C.

i only found [VCardImporter](https://github.com/itok/VCardImporter) and [AddressBookVcardImport](https://github.com/aussiegeek/AddressBookVcardImport) on github but they aren't in a final release state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this source: http://altoshstock.blogspot.com/2010/11/iphone-os-generate-vcard.html - you will find a link "*Download source code*". Be sure read comments to avoid some errors.

Comment: it works an i corrected the error and pushed it to github: https://github.com/carlj/ABContactHelper